# Correct Strategy for DB migrations in Go

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, sqlx

We have a go app where we use Postgres as a backend DB.
We use https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx for communicating with DB.
The code to read all rows from a table is as belows:

```
 rows, err := repo.db.Queryx(ListNodesQuery)
 if err != nil {
    repo.logger.Log("method", "ListNodes", "error", err)
    return nil, err
 }

 r := []*Node{}
 for rows.Next() {
    var n Node
    err = rows.StructScan(&n)
 }
```

After adding a new column in the DB, the code as expected errs as below

```
missing destination name type in *Node
```

as db table has more columns. Making change in code to update the struct simultaneously is ofcourse not possible.

I see that one way to turn this err off is to use db.Unsafe as documented [here](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx/blob/master/sqlx.go#L297)

Is there any other idiomatic way to deal with this situation?

Comment: Are you using a variant on `SELECT * FROM...` to query from the table? Change this to explicitly list the column names of interest. You save wasting database and network resources in moving data you discard, and you can explicitly update the query at the point the code is ready to receive values from the additional columns.

Comment: hmm...good point

Answer (score 1):

> Making change in code to update the struct simultaneously is ofcourse
>   not possible.

You can manage DB schemas inside your codebase and have some app startup code that automatically migrates DB to latest schema version to keep code and DB in sync.

One of the options is [github.com/golang-migrate](https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate).

Run this code on app start to update DB schema to latest version:

```
migrate, err := migrate.New("folder to sql scrips", "db connection string")
if err != nil {
    logger.Panic(err)
}
err = migrate.Up()
if err != nil {
    logger.Panic(err)
}
```

Comment: But If I have to rollback, then again I have to make change in code to update the struct.

Comment: You have to keep your DB schema and code schema in sync. Adding/removing columns is just one of many cases how that schema evolves. `GO` idiomatically wants to handle all errors including mapping explicitly. You are fighting with language intent when you want to swallow mapping inconsistencies.